# A person has 2 weighs in his hand, he jumps onto a trampoline and releases the weights. What is the new height the person will achieve?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy

> A person 60kg holds 2 weighs in his hand (30kg each), jumps from a height of 3m and releases the weights as he strikes a trampoline at height 0m, what height does the man achieve after the bounce?

Book solution: set both Potential energy initial equal to Potential energy final. (assume g=10) No energy loss at bounce

(120kg)(g)(3m)=(60kg)(g)(Height final)

Height Final= 6m

My doubt is, why does the person still have the same 3600 J of energy at the moment of bounce even though he released the weights at this moment (this was the assumption made by the book, and I have my doubts if its right)

I understand that independently and together the 3 objects have the same velocity when striking the trampoline (due to Kinematics), but when the person releases the masses wouldn't this reduction in mass result in a decrease of KE (for the man) at the bottom of the trampoline (because velocity stayed the same but mass was reduced from 120kg to 60kg)? (perhaps im wrong here)

so wouldnt the person just simply bounce to the original height of 3m? or less?

Answer (score 1):

The book is wrong and unclear.  It probably means that the person releases the weights at the bottom of the bounce. Then if person and weights are stationary when they are released, all the stored potential energy in the trampoline will become gravitational potential energy of just the person, when they are at their new maximum height (it would be 6m) - but the way the book asks it leads to an answer of 3m, as you said.

It's a rubbish question as we also have to assume the weights don't get in the way of the trampoline as it's pushing the person back up!

Comment: The trampoline will not get back to the original position if the weights are on it.  You are right,  bad question.  Maybe if he throws the weights out of the trampoline when he is at minimum point will work. Why won't the weights also be thrown up otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of the trampoline, there is no kinetic energy anyway. The kinetic energy of the weights has been used up in compressing the trampoline. Letting go of the weights at that point lets the trampoline bounce back and release the stored energy onto a smaller mass, which leads to a higher bounce.

The book makes things a bit unclear by treating the bounce as instantaneous. You only get the desired effect of you let go the weights halfway through the bounce, when the trampoline is maximally compressed.

Comment: thanks that clarification is good, im sure that is what my book implied. Thanks!

Comment: Feel free to upvote ;)